# How a C++ windows dialog based program to get system a status from time to time

Tags: c++, windows, forms, system, status

I made a program on the base of this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6003/Minimize-your-app-to-systray-in-easy-steps

The project from this link initially could not run under Visual Studio 2015, so I made some fixes to run. Here is the project I've made so far:

https://github.com/mitko-z/BatteryAlarm

This program I want to make it to get some system information from time to time and when an event happens a popup window to appear. But I am very new to C++ windows forms programming and I don't know where to put these checks in the project files (or maybe I should make new files???).

If anyone could give me some tips...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Management Instrumentation system provides a method by which your application may receive notification of system events (such as battery status).  If you are new to C++ and COM interfaces you might find it a bit overwhelming, but there is sample code available on the Microsoft web site.  Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for this link. But I think it is too much info for too less things to do. I know which procedure to use in order to get the battery status. The only thing I don't know is where to put this loop (or to use one if provided) to check for the battery status in some period of time i.e. I need something like check the battery status every 1 sec.

Comment: If you just want to run some code periodically you can use a timer.  Check out the SetTimer() and KillTimer() API calls.  The timer will send WM_TIMER messages to your application, which can then trigger your battery check.

Comment: that was my question about and I already managed to run the timers. But thanks for your answer!